# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined[reactjs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to count the remaining character using reactjs. I have defined the function which talks with the state and is passed down to the child component. In the child component i am getting an error of **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined** .

**app.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {max_char:32};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(charLength){
      console.log('charLength');
      this.setState({
        max_char:32 - charLength.length
      });
      console.log(this.state.max_char);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <Layout fixedHeader>
            <Content>
              <div className="page-content">
                <DeviceEventList />
                <DeviceDialog onChange={this.handleChange} />
              </div>
              <div className="empty-space">
              </div>
            </Content>
            </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**device-dialog.js**

```
class DeviceDialog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('this.props',this.props.onChange);
  }

  handleInputChange(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
    let name = event.target.value;
    this.props.onChange(name);
  }

  renderOwnADevice(){
    console.log('open',this.props.active_device_event.open);
    return(
      <div className="device-action">
        <Dialog open={this.props.active_device_event.open} onCancel={this.props.CancelDeviceEvent}>
          <DialogContent>
              <Textfield
                  onChange={()=> {this.handleInputChange(event)}}
                  pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?"
                  error="Input is not a number!"
                  label="Device Serial Number"
                  floatingLabel
                />
                <span style={{ float:'right'}}>character</span>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    )
  }


  render() {
    if ( !this.props.active_device_event){
      return <h5 style={{ textAlign:'center' }}>Click icon based on your work</h5>;
    }
    let icon_name = this.props.active_device_event.icon_name;
    if( icon_name == 'devices_other'){
      return (<div>Device Other</div>);
    }
    if( icon_name == 'add_circle_outline'){
      return (this.renderOwnADevice());
    }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess `onChange={()=> {this.handleInputChange(event)}}` should be `onChange={(event) => {this.handleInputChange(event)}}`. Now you're passing an event variable that's not defined.

As an aside: probably also better to bind the handler in the constructor like you did in `app.js` instead of having an anonymous function wrapper in your render.

Comment: Can you please clear my one confusion? What is the difference in between onChange={(event) => {this.handleInputChange(event)}} and onChange={this.handleInputChange} ? Which one is apt for which scenario?

Comment: You should always bind your handlers ahead of your render method and then just pass a reference to the bound handler in the render, like `onChange={this.handleInputChange}`. Binding it in the render instead (either via `.bind(this)` or by creating a function wrapper like you are doing) will create a new function on every render call, thus creating unnecessary overhead.

[eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) has a brief explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`event` is never defined in this line: `onChange={()=> {this.handleInputChange(event)}}`. Therefore your `handleChange` function is receiving an `undefined` value, not a string.

```
<Textfield
   onChange={this.handleInputChange}
   pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?"
   error="Input is not a number!"
   label="Device Serial Number"
   floatingLabel
/>
```

Your `this.handleInputChange` will now properly be passed the event argument.